# Why does adding a legend in this cartopy projection figure significantly increase the execution time (and how can fix this)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

So I have written a script for making figures that worked alright (see mock-up example below). But when I add a legend to the figure, the execution time increases a lot. I don't really understand what is happening here, I would naively expect that simply adding a legend is not a complex thing.

I suspect this has something to do with the cartopy projection, since it works alright if I don't use this.

What is the problem here, and how can I avoid this?

Problematic code:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Mockup dataset
num = 300
lat = np.linspace(-54,-59,num=num)
lon = np.linspace(-5,5, num=num)

data = np.outer(lat,lon)

ds = xr.DataArray(data=data,
                 dims=["lat", "lon"],
                 coords=dict(lon=lon, lat=lat))


# Map projection
map_proj = ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()

ax = plt.axes(projection=map_proj)
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
ax.set_extent([-3,4,-58,-54])

# Plot image
ds.plot(cmap="gray", 
        add_colorbar=False,
        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), # data projection
        subplot_kws={'projection': map_proj}) # map projection

# Plot contours
cs = ds.plot.contour(transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Make legend
proxy = [matplotlib.lines.Line2D([],[], c=pc.get_color()[0]) for pc in cs.collections]
labels = ["foo"] * len(cs.collections)
plt.legend(proxy, labels)
```

Code without cartopy projection:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Mockup dataset
num = 300
lat = np.linspace(-54,-59,num=num)
lon = np.linspace(-5,5, num=num)

data = np.outer(lat,lon)

ds = xr.DataArray(data=data,
                 dims=["lat", "lon"],
                 coords=dict(lon=lon, lat=lat))

# Plot image
ds.plot(cmap="gray", 
        add_colorbar=False) # map projection

# Plot contours
cs = ds.plot.contour()

# Make legend
proxy = [matplotlib.lines.Line2D([],[], c=pc.get_color()[0]) for pc in cs.collections]
plt.legend(proxy, labels)
```

Comment: Set the legends location manually.  Otherwise it tries to find the “best” location and that can be slow if you have lots of data.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks, worked like charm! If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.legend(proxy, labels)` defaults to `loc='best'` which uses an algorithm that can be slow if you have lots of data in your axes, and particularly slow if that data also has complicated transforms.  Instead do `ax.legend(proxy, labels, loc='upper right')` manually. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html